# Cannot build CocoaPods in Release, but no problems in debug

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to build my app in Release and archive it.
It fails at

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-ABPadLockScreen
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

As said, it compiles fine in debug and runs in Simulator with no issues at all.

Some of my settings:

```
//:configuration = Debug
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited)

//:configuration = Release
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited)

//:configuration = Debug
ARCHS = armv7s armv7
SDKROOT = iphoneos
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = YES
VALID_ARCHS = armv7 armv7s

//:configuration = Release
ARCHS = armv7s armv7
SDKROOT = iphoneos
VALID_ARCHS = armv7 armv7s
```

Do you have any idea on how to be able to build release?

Comment: Share your pod file please. Did you add recently release target to project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the architecture to standard 32-bit.
This solved the problem and the app is now compilable.